# numpy.ufunc operation equivalent

Tags: python, numpy

I have 4D `numpy` array `a` and 3D array `b`. Also I have 2D arrays of indices `i0`, `j0`, `k0`. Suppose I want to use the following construction:

```
np.add.at(a, (slice(None), k0, i0, j0), b)
```

As fas as I understood, `a[slice(None), k0, i0, j0] += b` is not equivalent to this `np.add.at`.
The question is how can this `np.add.at` line can be replaced with a simple `numpy` adding `a[...] += b[...]` properly?

Comment: `add.at` is needed if the indices have duplicates.

Comment: Why *i0*, *j0* and *k0* are **2-D**? Does each row define a slice in a respective dimension (*k0* - second dimension, *i0* - third and *j0* fourth (for "a* array) and "dimension - 1" in "b")?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that *i0*, *j0* and *k0* are **2-D** arrays.

This is why I assumed that each row in these arrays defines a 3-D slice
in *b* array (each array in the respective dimension).

For the test I defined these arrays as:

```
k0 = np.array([[0,1],[1,2]])
i0 = np.array([[1,3],[2,4]])
j0 = np.array([[0,2],[2,4]])
```

so that the first 3-D slice from *b* is: `b[0:1, 1:3, 0:2]`.

Because *k0*, *i0* and *j0* (taken "by row") define consecutive slices,
you can not join them in a single instruction.
My proposition is to perform your addition in the following loop:

```
for sl in np.dstack([k0, i0, j0]):
    idx = tuple(np.insert(np.r_[np.apply_along_axis(
        lambda row: slice(*row), 0, sl)], 0, slice(None)))
    a[tuple(idx)] += b[tuple(idx[1:])]
```

*idx* is a 4-tuple to index array "*a*". The first element is *slice(None)* -
operate on all elements in the first dimension.
Following elements are slices for following dimensions.

To index *b* array the same *idx* is used, but without the first
element.

To test the above code, I defined both arrays as:

```
aDim = (2, 2, 4, 4)
bDim = aDim[1:]
a = np.arange(1, np.array(aDim).prod() + 1).reshape(aDim)
b = np.arange(501, np.array(bDim).prod() + 501).reshape(bDim)
```

(print them to see the initial content).

After my code was executed, *a* contains:

```
array([[[[  1,   2,   3,   4],
         [510, 512,   7,   8],
         [518, 520,  11,  12],
         [ 13,  14,  15,  16]],

        [[ 17,  18,  19,  20],
         [ 21,  22,  23,  24],
         [ 25,  26, 554, 556],
         [ 29,  30, 562, 564]]],


       [[[ 33,  34,  35,  36],
         [542, 544,  39,  40],
         [550, 552,  43,  44],
         [ 45,  46,  47,  48]],

        [[ 49,  50,  51,  52],
         [ 53,  54,  55,  56],
         [ 57,  58, 586, 588],
         [ 61,  62, 594, 596]]]])
```